# CloudMade Marker Overlays - Can The Z-Index Be Controlled?

Tags: javascript, overlay, openlayers, layer, cloudmade

Does the CloudMade API have the ability to control the z-order or z-index of the marker overlays (e.g.icons)?

I have used this before in Google Maps to make certain icons with more importance draw over the top of other icons with lesser importance (especially in some zoom levels where they may bunch together).

The Google Maps GMarker has the zIndexProcess option to handle this. Does anyone know if CloudMade has this facility? I have scoured the API docs and found nothing. Or does anyone here perhaps have an ad-hoc method that ensures one marker (or group of makers) will be drawn on a layer above the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this feature is not available at CloudMade, but I'll add it to our Feature Requests list..